# GridView: Adding custom row every 20 items

Tags: android, gridview

I have a standard GridView displaying images. I would like for every 20 items/images that are shown, a custom layout to be shown.

Here is an good example of what I mean:

[image]

Would anyone know how to achieve this? any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use recyclerView, check number count if it %20 every time add custom row

Answer (score 1):

> Would anyone know how to achieve this?

I did it. You can achieve this easily by using `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager`  and 2 view types in `RecyclerView.Adapter`.
You can see codes below: With type `TYPE_ADS`, you span colum by 2. With normal item `TYPE_ITEM`, you don't span colum (means value = 1)

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_ADS:
                        return 2;
                    case MyAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm); 
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: What is MyAdapter.TYPE_ADS and TYPE_ITEM refer to? is it an int defined in the adapter class?

Comment: Correct. Having 2 types int in your `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Based on item types have relevant layout. You can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)